# WCF Authorization using IIS and ACLs

Tags: wcf, security, iis, authorization, wcf-security

i'm trying to secure some WCF services. I'd like to use IIS or the Web.config todo all of the heavy lifting/configuration if possible. I don't want to embed anything in my code - thought I know that may not be feasible. If possible, I'd like to achieve this without having to resort to AspCompatibilityMode :(

I'm using a custom BasicHttp binding with TransportCredential enabled.

This works fine. Any valid domain or machine account seems to validate against the service.

My problem is I only want users from specific windows groups to be able to access my service. I wanted to use ACLs on the actual folders to achieve this, but I don't think it is possible.

Would appreciate your help!

Thanks
TM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config try the following:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />  
<identity impersonate="false" />
<authorization>
   <allow users="MYDOMAIN\YourGroup" />
   <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

This will block it at the web config level. You can also put an ACL on your folder. Note the Windows authentication and the impersonate = false means that it is the users credentials that are being used to access the directory.

Comment: Hey Shiraz, this works a treat! Thank you. However it only with ASP Compatibility Mode enabled, is there a way todo something similar without ASP compatibility mode enabled?? Many thanks, TM

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx it does not look like it is possible

Comment: Thanks Shiraz, I think this actually suits my problem domain, so will go with it. TM

Comment: Your comments about ASP.NET Compatibility Mode and the provided Microsoft article were helpful in me solving my issue regarding Authorization Rules not working for my WCF service - thank you!  I wrote a little more detail here in case it's helpful to anyone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67712447/why-wont-authorization-rules-in-iis-restrict-access-to-my-wcf-service